# Optional shared library

Tags: android, shared-libraries, cpu-architecture

I am developing an application that must be compatible with all Android device architectures. Also, some of these devices may have UHF reader capabilities that I want to exploit.

For these special devices, I have a shared library for the `armeabi` architecture. In devices with this architecture, the application works fine (whether they have UHF reader or not). However, for devices with other architectures, the application is not even installed, with an `INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS` error.

I want to know if there is any way to make the library optional, so that devices of other architectures simply ignore it.
It would be ok if I could explicitly load the library (or not, depending on the architecture) using

```
System.loadLibrary("DeviceAPI");
```

but I don't know how to fix the installation problem. I want to avoid generating more than one APK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is surely not the best way to go, but it seems to work. I simply created a dummy shared library for every missing platform and renamed the .so files with the same name as my `armeabi` library file. The app installs now in every platform and I only have to catch the proper exceptions at initialization or check the device architecture.